# Customize Error Pages for HTTP error codes?

Tags: hana

How can I have custom error pages for HTTP errors like 401, 403, 404, ... in HANA (version 1.00.122.08)?

Comment: Are you referring to XS (classic) applications or XSA applications?

Comment: it is XS classic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this question refers to the XSC (classic) version of the web application server, the answer is: there is no option to customize the error messages.
On option to deal with this is to handle all requests through an inverse proxy/load balancer and use its custom error messages.